# Android get inner json array from json array

Tags: android, arrays, json

Hello guys I have a tricky problem which I've been solving for hours.

This is my JSON response:

```
  {
"DATA": [
    {
        "Name": "Aha",
        "ListData": [
            {
                "ID": 1
            },
            {
                "ID": 2
            },
            {
                "ID": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
 try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("DATA");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray arr = data.getJSONArray(Constants.LIST_DATA);
            for(int j = 0; j < arr.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject innerData = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                int id = innerData.getInt(Constants.ID);

                item = new HashMap<>();
                item.put(Constants.ID, id);
                itemList.add(item);
            }
        }

    } catch(JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSONException", "" + e.toString());
    }
```

But I'm only getting the correct size (3) of the array but I'm getting the same ID which 1. What seems to be wrong with my code? Any help would greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Result is something like this:

```
ID=1,ID=1,ID=1
```

Whereas my expected is:

```
ID=1,ID=2,ID=3
```

Comment: your id is int , so read by this code ```int id = innerData.getInt(Constants.ID);``` and ```arr.getJSONObject(j);```

Comment: JSONObject innerData = arr.getJSONObject(i); this is wrong replace with  JSONObject innerData = arr.getJSONObject(j);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have used

```
 JSONObject innerData = arr.getJSONObject(j);
```

you're doing second loop with `j=0` and you're trying to getting `JSONString` from first loop.